# Is it possible host other protocols besides HTTP inside ASP.NET on Azure Websites?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

This probably sounds like an 'out-there' idea, but I would like to host non-HTTP services inside Azure Websites. I would like my code to be able to respond to FTP or SMTP requests on port 80, in addition to HTTP. Specifically, I would like to take in files from a net camera via FTP, process them, and store them in blob storage, etc. I'm aware I could do a VM, but Websites appeals to me because it is cheaper. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time it is not possible to host protocols other than HTTP or Web Sockets in Azure Websites - now known as Azure Web Apps.

You can do it in Cloud Services or in VMs, but not in Web Apps.

You can submit feature ideas or suggestions to http://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback .

Hope this helps.  Healy in Tampa.